# How to emded my own video player on facebook to play shared videos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video-streaming

Is it possible to emded my own video player on facebook to play shared videos, so I can see the video directly in the Facebook like a example Youtube.

is that possible with PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

use og tags. below is real working example:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.video.az/ru/video/106798/atv-nin-canli-yayiminda-istrakcinin-ureyi-getdi">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.video.az/assets/player/player.swf?st=p8kVe19GxUsUstlZpik5wtlhcWotsSoDe87G2CoZpik5wtHL41nU=f6GwZeO">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720">
```

Comment: I have used same meta tag but still video not playing on facebook, do you please any working URL?

Comment: I think facebook has cached Your link.

use facebook debug to check and flush cache: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

here is working url: http://video.az/ru/video/106789/the-game-before-the-game

You can check it